# check if row updated or not in sqlite?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am using sqlite database in my iphone app.
I am writing code for update record on certain condition. While my query is correct how can I detect that any row is updated or not..
I had tried `SQLITE_DONE` but it shows that query executed or not... What to use..
Here is my code..

```
const char *sqlStmt = [strQuery UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStmt, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        isSucceed = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE;
        //isSucceed = YES;
    }
```

what will be in place `SQLITE_DONE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [sqlite3_changes()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html).